# CSS selector within stacked lists

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to style the nav in a template theme that I neither wrote nor picked.  The nav uses lists in its structures and the children at various levels have the same class. I'm hoping someone can help me find the right CSS selector to pick the third level down. Here is the basic structure:

```html
<nav class="nonbounce desktop vertical">
 <ul>
  <li class="item sub active">
   <a class="itemLink" href="https://sitename/tools/" title="Tools">Tools</a>
   <ul class="subnav">
    <li class="subitem">
     <a class="subitemLink" href="https://sitename/tools/outdoors/" title="Outdoors">Outdoors</a>
     <ul class="subnav">
      <li class="subitem">
      <a class="subitemLink" href="https://www.safenready.net/tools/outdoors/mowers/" title="mowers">Mowers</a>  THIS ONE!!!
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

What I need to do is grab the 3rd level down (called Mowers in example). 
My ultimate goal is to style this level and move it vertically but first I need to be able to modify only that level with CSS.
This is a new site but I can provide the real site URL if that would help.
jc

Comment: Kindly consider up voting / approving the answer that resolved your query, so that the answer can be helpful for other community members.

Comment: Since you have classes applied, why can't you just use the specific class (`.subitem` or `.subnav` or `.subitem > a` or just `a.subitemLink`)?

Comment: because i want to effect only third one if  `subitemLink` class use multiple times, the css effected every where there is the same class so i catch the `title`. and there are many way to do this which  wrote by you in your comment like this `a.subitemLink`

Comment: Fair enough. I, personally, would just assign an ID then rather than calling the title attribute in the CSS to keep the CSS more streamlined. And ID would be just as unique as the title attribute.. and take an equal amount of time to implement. But the title attribute does work.

Comment: I can't modify the classes because the vendor who does the site (LightSpeed) has caveats about updates and support if you modify the templates so I have to make it work the way it's coded. Bummer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```css
.subitemLink[title~="mowers"] {
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nonbounce desktop vertical">
 <ul>
  <li class="item sub active">
   <a class="itemLink" href="https://sitename/tools/" title="Tools">Tools</a>
   <ul class="subnav">
    <li class="subitem">
     <a class="subitemLink" href="https://sitename/tools/outdoors/" title="Outdoors">Outdoors</a>
     <ul class="subnav">
      <li class="subitem">
      <a class="subitemLink" href="https://www.safenready.net/tools/outdoors/mowers/" title="mowers">Mowers</a>  THIS ONE!!!
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I like this idea but the subitems (product categories) are defined dynamically by category hierarchy. A product category may be the 3rd item in one group but the second item in a different nav group. If I grab by name, that changes the entire nav look.  Example  (not using mowers)

>Emergency & First Aid
    >> First Aid Kits  {level 2}

>C.E.R.T.
   >>Team Gear
    >>> Clothing
    >> Literature
    >>Equipment
    >>>First Aid Kits  {level 3}
I need to grab by position.  Sorry about formatting - I'm new here.

@Lokesh Gupta